# Removing Trend and Seasonality Time Series Python

Tags: python, time-series

I have a time series data were I need to remove the trend and seasonality components from it. I was wondering whether I could use seasonal_decompose() function in Python and extract residual as follows:

```
result =  seasonal_decompose(self.series, model='additive',freq=frequency) 
residual = result.resid
```

Or should I apply well know detrending and deseasonalizing methods (such as by differencing), and if I where to apply such methods, shall I detrend first then deseasonalize or vice versa ??

Answer (score 2):

As [No free lunch theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem) suggests, there is no universal model that can beat all other models on any kind of data. You should definitely try differencing and [Seasonal ARIMA](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.html) in addition to seasonal decomposition you'v already tried. The criterion of model selection is performance of a model on *your* data. With ARIMA, you don't need to detrend. Check out [this comprehensive tutorial](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.html).